# Android Studio: Cannot resolve method 'getWindowManager' in 'Context'

Tags: android

Can anyone help me correct this error in AdMobAdvertisment.java

I'm unsure what to replace it with.

Thanks in advance.

Image: https://snipboard.io/cK76P1.jpg

```
private AdSize getAdSize() {
    try{
        // Step 2 - Determine the screen width (less decorations) to use for the ad width.
        Display display = mContext.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        DisplayMetrics outMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        display.getMetrics(outMetrics);
```

Answer (score 1):

To get access to `getWindowManager`. your context must be `AppCompatActivity` or `Activity`.

So you need to cast it to one of them.

For example:

```
        Display display = ((AppCompatActivity) mContext).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        DisplayMetrics outMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        display.getMetrics(outMetrics);
```

Comment: Thanks Mayur..

Is this correct?

If I click import class it seems to fix the error

https://snipboard.io/C8DOox.jpg


https://snipboard.io/trj4Ev.jpg

Comment: @EMar Yes. It's correct. You can import it.